# Django relative urls and https

Tags: python, django, ssl, https

I have a Django project using https for certain part of the url (/account/,  /admin/, /purchase/).

When on one of this page in https mode, all the relative inner links {% url foo %} will point to https://my_url.

However I do not want to have those pages shown as https :home, contacts ...

What are the solutions for this kind of requirements ?

Enforcing absolute url ?

```
 http://{{ domain }}{% url foo %}
```

is not too nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tomasz suggests, one way to do it is to set up middleware to redirect to and from https as necessary. Here's [one implementation](http://www.rosslawley.co.uk/2010/08/using-django-to-serve-parts-of-your.html) - the idea is to decorate those views that should be served under https, and when the user navigates to a view that shouldn't be secure from one that is, the middleware redirects them automatically back to the http version of the page.

Answer (score 4):

Idea: you can use a custom middleware to redirect from https to http (or vice versa) for centrain URLs or URL patterns. This could also be done in Apache (or other web server) configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Could use your webserver to rewrite to http, that way Django doesn't even need to know.

Answer (score 2):

I find [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/85/) takes care of the situation nicely. Views that need SSL will have them, via a redirect from the http to https version of the url, and vice-versa.

Yes, on a https page, the outbound link to a non-https page in your site will still start with https, but the user will be redirected to the http version.

(There is a gotcha, however: it won't work if you're posting from http to https and vice versa)

Answer (score 2):

maybe this can serve for you

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ContributedMiddleware#SSLMiddlewarebyStephenZabel

an contributed SSL Middleware