# Django named URLs and HTTPS/SSL

Tags: django, https

I'm currently working on securing my Django website with SSL. I'd like certain URL patterns to be accessible only via HTTPS. The single most important thing to do is to secure the login site. There is this form where user inputs their login/password into a form and the form is POSTed to the server. In the login page template I have something like

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url login %}">
```

and in my `urls.py` one of the patterns is something like

```
    url(r'^login/$', 'mySiteLogin', name='login'),
```

Now I've found some resources suggesting that I should use a middleware that will rewrite `http` to `https`, for example this: [Django relative urls and https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148009/django-relative-urls-and-https). But logging in cannot be done this way - it's no use to rewrite the protocol when the user has already POSTed their password in plaintext!

So I'm thinking, can I somehow tell `{% url %}` to use `https`? I'm thinking of a solution that will use a decorator to mark views that require encryption and then some tag similar to `{% url %}` will use this info and create a link with `https` when required.

Or is there some other way?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Is your `{% url %}` tag outputting the protocol and domain, as well as the path? E.g. does it output `https://yourdomain.com/login/`? Because I don’t think it’s meant to be used like that.

Comment: Well, the original Django tag outputs only the absolute path of the URL, so no domain and no protocol. But I'd like it to output both and change the protocol to https when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> But logging in cannot be done this way
>   - it's no use to rewrite the protocol when the user has already POSTed their
>   password in plaintext!

Just serve the login page itself over HTTPS. This seems to be a good idea in general.

> “By January 5, it was clear that an
>   entire country’s worth of passwords
>   were in the process of being stolen
>   right in the midst of the greatest
>   political upheaval in two
>   decades.”—which is why you shouldn’t
>   serve your login form over HTTP even
>   though it POSTs over HTTPS.
>
> http://simonwillison.net/2011/Jan/24/

In a nutshell, ISPs from Tunisia injected malicious JavaScript code into the login pages of Facebook to steal user logins.

Comment: Wow, the Tunisian story sounds veeery serious... Anyway, the problem stays the same: I have a link to the login page written as `{% url login %}`. How to make it output a https link? Or how to craft my own version of `{% url %}`?

Comment: True that the login page should be over HTTPS, but then how to generate the link to the login page itself (eg, from the home page)? Adding {% url login %} to the home page will generate a relative link, which will lead you to the insecure login page if the home page is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should instead look at middleware solutions that does redirection between HTTP and HTTPS. One example: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/85/